# How to selectively delete Google App Engine data backup set in google cloud storage via the admin console?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

I want to delete old backup in Google Cloud Storage.

The 'delete' button is not enabled after items are selected

[image]

Why 'delete' is disabled?

Comment: exactly. there is no option to delete the items on web interface. I am facing the same problem. And cannot delete the buckets too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web interface is not working (still now). But you can use "gsutil". It is a command line tool to access the cloud storage. For this you have to download and install the Google Cloud SDK. Perform gcloud init and gcloud auth login. Select your project and login into the cloud platform.

Now from command line you can use these commands-

```
 gsutil rm gs://<bucket-url>/<file-name> .........to delete a file
 gsutil rm -r gs://<bucket-url>...................to delete a bucket
```